# Big Data integration for MAX-CSP solvers?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, bigdata, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction

We have huge MAX-CSP instances with millions of variables and constraints.

Is there any Big Data integration with Apache Spark or similar for any CSP solvers? Or some other available way of Big Data parallelization?

If not, is there a chance that MAX-CSP can be reasonably handled in parallel at all? Or maybe only under certain conditions using the structure of the problem?

Can't find anything about this... Only vice versa, managing Big Data processes etc. by constraint programming :-/

Best regards

Luma

I already searched for:

- "Spark" and "Big Data" with all CSP solvers shown at http://xcsp.org/
- "Big Data constraint programming" etc.

Comment: Whats the problem with the current approach? Details? Discrete opt is terrible in regards to parallelization and even more given spark and co's computation models. Cp and big data is hard to merge. Some cp propagators already have quadratic or cubic complexity.

Comment: We have experts formulating lots of interconnecting constraints that should be hold on our data, but most real-world data include some errors / inaccuracy / etc. We like to find a preferably small set of fixes to the dataset (according to some defined metric) in order to fulfill the constraints. And maybe show which constraints might be stated incorrectly because they cause very many data fixes. With SQL we can't do such optimization using all constraints at once. Better use some simple hill climbing etc. to try single fixes sequentially and measure the constraint violations with SQL?